# How to make floating content at once?

Tags: html, css

This my following code:

```html
<div class="coupon-price">
  <div class="">
    <span class="coupon-new-price"> 65.000</span>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <span class="coupon-old-price"> 130.000</span>
  </div>
  <div class="disc" style="width:31px;height:31px;position: absolute;float:right;right:6px;z-index:10000;background: red;color:white;border-radius: 70px;line-height:31px;text-align:center;font-size:10px;">
    50%
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is how to make the red circle parallel with price?

Comment: shall that red circle at right side of the page or just next to price?

Comment: next to @S.Serp

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code to make the disc parallel with price. Let me know if it helps.

```html
<div class="coupon-price">
 <div class="">
         <span class="coupon-new-price"> 65.000</span>
    </div>
    <div class="">
         <span class="coupon-old-price"> 130.000</span>
    </div>
         
   <div class="disc" style="width:31px;height:31px;position: absolute;float:right;right:6px;z-index:10000;background: red;color:white;border-radius: 70px;line-height:31px;text-align:center;font-size:10px; top: 5px">
     
         50%     
   </div>
         
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly see the below code it may helps you.

```
<div class="coupon-price">
    <div class=""> <span class="coupon-new-price"> 65.000</span> </div>
    <div class="" style="position: relative;"> <span class="coupon-old-price"> 130.000</span>
        <div class="disc" style="width:31px;height:31px;position: absolute;float:right;right:6px;z-index:10000;background: red;color:white;border-radius: 70px;line-height:31px;text-align:center;font-size:10px; top:0;"> 50% </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

do you want somthing like this:

**HTML**

```
  <div class="coupon-price" style="position: relative;padding-right:50px;">
    <div class="">
         <span class="coupon-new-price"> 65.000</span>
    </div>
    <div class="">
         <span class="coupon-old-price"> 130.000</span>
    </div>

   <div class="disc" style="width:31px;height:31px;position: absolute;right:6px;z-index:10000;background: red;color:white;border-radius: 70px;line-height:31px;text-align:center;font-size:10px;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto;">

         50%                    
   </div>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wcmdv2xg/5/)

[**Source**](http://learnlayout.com/position.html)

If you are going to use absolute position for an element, understand it before you use it read the source for more and check the fiddle for excpected o/p.

```
.coupon-price {
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
.coupon-price:after {
  clear:left
}
.disc {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:-50px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color:#f00;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following snippet

```css
.disc {
  width: 31px;
  height: 31px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top:10px;
  z-index: 10000;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 70px;
  line-height: 31px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.coupon-price {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid
}

.price * {
  display: block;
}

.price {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="coupon-price">
  <div class="price">
    <span class="coupon-new-price"> 65.000</span>

    <span class="coupon-old-price"> 130.000</span>
  </div>

  <div class="disc" style="">

    50%
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

for position absolute, you should have a position relative parent. i set also  `padding-right:50px` to parent div to provide space to show the red circle.

Note: if you want to see the red circle at right side of page, remove `display: inline-block;` from main div.

```html
<p>test</p>

<div class="coupon-price" style="position:relative; border:1px solid silver; display: inline-block; padding-right:50px">
 <div class="">
         <span class="coupon-new-price"> 65.000</span>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <span class="coupon-old-price"> 130.000</span>
  </div>
 
  <div class="disc" style="position: absolute; right:6px; top:3px; width:31px; height:31px; z-index:1000; background: red; color:white; border-radius: 70px; line-height:31px; text-align:center; font-size:10px; "> 50% 
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: did you check this? is it what you want? whats your feedback?